# How do I align my text and icon in Listview in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I want to recreate a ListView as shown below. However when I'm trying to replicate it, my text is overflowing and the image isn't getting aligned with the text. 
This is my code:

```
Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>\[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>\[
                              CircleAvatar(),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>\[
                                   Text(
                                  'Hello John',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                   SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'the fox ran over the tree and jumped over the dog and cat that were sleeping under it ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.0,
                                  ),
                                \],
                              ),
                            \],
                          ),
                        \],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

This is my output:

[image]
Trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is `ListTile` available for the exact purpose.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
​
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
​
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(children: [
        DemoListTile(),
        DemoListTile(),
        DemoListTile(),
        DemoListTile(),
      ])),
    );
  }
}
​
class DemoListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        title: const Text("Hello World"),
        isThreeLine:
            true, //will fix the alignment if the subtitle text is too big
        subtitle: const Text(
            "Flutter demo big ss text here and there to break things everywhere, but still can't break things here"),
        leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right));
  }
}
```

---

which gives

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

To make text overflowing i use often the AutoSizeText Package:

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

With the AutoSizeText Widget your code can look like this:

```
Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
   child: Container(
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120,
       child: AutoSizeText(
           'the fox ran over the tree and jumped over the dog and cat that were sleeping under it ',
            style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 16.0,
                 color: Colors.black,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            maxLines: 5,
        ),
     ),
 ),
```

With MediaQuery you can give the Container a dynamic width depending on your device width.

Optionale: You can give the Container a padding and you can set the textAlign property  to justify for better look.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already has mentioned, `ListTile()` would do the job perfectly.

If you want to stick with your own layout for the ListView elements, I would recommend you to you use the `flex()`-Widget for position the different parts inside the Column and to use the `Expanded()`-Widget for moving something (like an arrow) to the end of the list element.
Of course you can also use `flex()`-Widgets for the row to push the arrow to the end of the list element.

To prevent text overflow, just use the `TextOverflow.ellipsis` or something similar.